# How to convert type of Input<uint16_t> to common data type(such as int) in halide::generator?

Tags: c++, halide

I am a new guy trying Halide programming. I met an issue when porting some Halide code into Android via `Halide::Generator`. Below is my code:

```
#include "Halide.h"
using namespace Halide;
using namespace Halide::ConciseCasts;
using namespace std;
Func align_layer(int i) {
    Func ret;
    Var x, y;

    ret(x, y) = i;

    return ret;
}

class TestGenerator : public Halide::Generator<TestGenerator> 
{
    public:
    Input<uint16_t> value{"value"};

    // We then define a method that constructs and return the Halide
    // pipeline:
    void generate() 
    {
        int test = value;
    }
};

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(TestGenerator, test_generator)
```

When I compile it, I got below error:

> generator_test.cpp:31:14: error: cannot convert ‘Halide::Internal::GeneratorBase::Input {aka Halide::GeneratorInput}’ to ‘int’ in initialization
>     int test = value;

I did some try:
`int test = (int)(value);`
or use case converting, all did not work.

Could any one give me a hand?

Comment: Off-topic: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) – same applies for other namespaces, and the more you import, the greater the risk of name clashes...

Comment: Have you peaked into [documentation](https://halide-lang.org/docs/namespace_halide.html)? Have you had a look at the [tutorials](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_introduction.html)? I did so, just to notice that this isn't intended usage... Seeing what you try to do I think you started far to early with generators. Recommendation: Work through the more basic tutorials to learn what you actually can do with the elements defined in Halide before you move to more advanced concepts like generators.

Comment: what does the error tell you? that `value` is not an integer type... it's an `Halide::Internal::GeneratorBase::Input<uint16_t>`. So you cannot convert it to int. Do what @Aconcagua says

Comment: Thanks to  Aconcagua and JHBonarius. I am investigating tutorials.